# How to mock executeNamedQuery(query, params) for Junit Testing

Tags: java, jpa, junit, entitymanager, hibernate-generic-dao

@Repository
public class DAOImpl extends GenericDaoImpl implements SomeDAO {

```
@Autowired
EntityManager em;

@Override
public List<PropertyURL> getProperties(String env) throws Exception{
    List<String> inParam = new ArrayList<>();
    inParam.add(env);
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put(ProEnum.ENV.getProperty(), inParam);
    List<PropertyURL> URL = null;
    String query = "PropertyURL.getProperty";
    URL = executeNamedQuery(query, params);
    return URL;
}
```

How can i mock  executeNamedQuery(query, params) call and return some thing  Ex:Mockito.when(entityManagerMock.merge(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(someObject);

Comment: Before trying to mock an `EntityManager`, I'd ask myself if it wouldn't be better to test a  component that interacts with JPA directly using integration tests. If you mock out `executeNamedQuery` and only run a unit test, how are you going to verify that your query works?

Comment: We have both integration tests and unit tests,but for unit tests we need to cover the whole method to see the flow is going as expected.